# update parent window on dialogbox close WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to update my Main window when I close child window. I'm updating listview record and then on ok button I'm closing my child window and I'm trying to update my parent window without MVVM technique

```
 private void btnDialogOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       MainWindow mn = new MainWindow();
        mn.InitializeComponent();
        List<Scheme> items = new List<Scheme>();
        List<Scheme> objScheme = oSchemeBLL.getAllSchemeListBLL();
        mn = new MainWindow(objScheme);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is, but you're creating a new instance of MainWindow at the beginning of your snippet there, declaring an items collection that is apparently never used, then creating yet another new instance of MainWindow. If you're trying to access an already-existing instance of MainWindow, you need to grab a reference to it rather than creating new references.

Comment: actually i have a child window, i did some updates. my main window contains a ListView. i want to update it when i'm going to close my child window. here i'm calling a function of parent window to update my listview but  its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of `Closed` event, that is raised when the `Window` is about to close. Here's an example that you can implement in your parent window in the declaration of you child window:

```
Window TestWindow = new Window();
TestWindow.Closed += (s, eventarg) =>
{
    // Your method to update parent window
};
```

Comment: in your method it gives me error on e cannot b created in this scope. because the name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: @navi this error is because there's already a variable named 'e' in this scope, all you have to do is change the name. Already updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try to suscribe to `Closed` event of `child window` from `parent window`.

```
Window child_window;
child_window.Closed += child_Closed;
```

In that event handler, you can get the viewmodel from your child window, and access to data.

```
private void child_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Window child;
   ViewModel vm;

   //Cast sender to windows type
   child = (Window)sender;

   //Cast window datacontext to viewmodel
   vm = (ViewModel)child.DataContext;

   //Access to properties or whatever you need
   vm.Foo
}
```